# Changes on Virtual Host Definition have no effect - Apache2

Tags: server, apache2

I use Ubuntu 14.04.4 and Apache 2.4.7

In the directory `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` are to files called `000-default.conf` for http connections and `ssl.conf` for https connections, which works fine.

After adding the line `Redirect permanent / https://mysite.example.com/` to the `000-default.conf` all http connections became redirected to https.

But in my case from outside the network, where the server is located, i was not anymore able to get acces to the site. Because everything works before, I deleted the line `Redirect permanent / https://mysite.example.com/` in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` and restarted the apache, but I'm still not able to get access from outside and the redirection is still active.

Why is this the case? And how can I undo this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser you used has correctly interpreted a `Redirect Permanent` and thus automatically redirects from http://mysite.example.com to https://mysite.example.com . In Firefox, you can clean this cache by [removing all the history for mysite.example.com](https://superuser.com/questions/467999/clear-301-redirect-cache-in-firefox).

As you can't connect to your https-enabled website: is port 443 (HTTPS) open on the firewall? Is Apache listening on that port (it should normally do that by default)?

Comment: The admin says that the port 443 is open on the firewall and in `/etcapache2/ports.conf` apache is listening on port 80 `Listen 80` and listening on 443 `<IfModule mod-ssl.c>Listen 443</IfModule>`.

Comment: I just scanned the external ip with a port scanner. 80 is open and 443 is closed. Got it! Thank you